# Revit API: Creating a new Footprint roof

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I'm having trouble creating a footprint roof using revit 2018 API.
Basically, I'm calling this:

```
doc.Create.NewFootPrintRoof(ca, doc.GetElement(roofsInstances[0].LevelId), roofsInstances[0].RoofType)
```

And:

- "ca" is a valid *Autodesk.Revit.DB.CurveArray* object. It's a closed loop.
- "doc.GetElement(roofsInstances[0].LevelId)" is a valid *Autodesk.Revit.DB.Level* object
- And "roofsInstances[0].RoofType" is a valid *Autodesk.Revit.DB.RoofType* object

When I call it, it returns: *Exception: Value cannot be null.*

Any idea on what could be the issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey Arnaud, looks like one of the args isnt correct - could you post more code to show us how you built each arg?

Comment: Dear Callum, as I was trying to provide you with a reproducible example, I found out the solution :) I'll post it below! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found out what was wrong. First, this method needs a 4th argument, a "out attribute" (sorry, I had never seen that before..) which needs to be a *ModelCurveArray*.
The problem was that even when I gave a *ModelCurveArray* object as the 4th argument, it was then complaining that it expected a *StrongBox[ModelCurveArray]*. Never heard of that either.

Anyway, I used this as the 4th argument:

```
footPrintToModelCurveMapping = clr.StrongBox[ModelCurveArray](ModelCurveArray())
```

And it works.